# Node.js: appending to readable stream WHILE it is piped to a writable stream?

Tags: node.js, pipe, fs, nodejs-stream, nodejs-server

My server receives udp packets of audio buffers.
I would like to stream these incoming chunks to Google's text-to-speech API.

Using fs streams, is it possible to achieve this in a manner that goes something like this?:

```
let stream = fs.createReadStream("empty-file-name").pipe(myOutputStreamToAPI);

dgramserver.on('message', (msg, rinfo) => {
        stream.push(msg)
}
```

In this rough sketch, I would create an empty (possible?) stream, or alternatively create the stream upon the first recieved packet, and the keep pushing to the stream as more packets come in.

Is this possible?

How else can my desired outcome be achieved? Namely, after a readable-stream is piped to a writable-stream, I wish to ADD TO THE READABLE STREAM DYNAMICALLY AND AT DISTINTC TIMES.

This question can also be asked like this:
How can I create a readable stream out of dynamically incoming udp packets?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this give you answer

```
const Stream = require('stream')

const readableStream = new Stream.Readable()
const writableStream = new Stream.Writable()

writableStream._write = (chunk, encoding, next) => {
    console.log(chunk.toString())
    next()
}

readableStream.pipe(writableStream)

readableStream.push('ping!')
readableStream.push('pong!')

writableStream.end()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This looks like exactly what I need.
Two things though:
1. unless I push a null value to the readableStream after the 'ping''pong', I get a "readable._read not implemented error", any idea what is meant to be implemented in the body of the method?
2. Can you explain to me the _write method and why you have implemented it?
Your code works when I change the writable stream to process.stdout so it will probably work for my needs but can you explain to me what you intended? thanks

Comment: For 1st you need to push (null) at the end which tells the source ends. For 2nd _write function MUST NOT be called by application code directly. It should be implemented by child classes, and called by the internal Writable class methods only.
Eg: 
_write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    fs.write(this.fd, chunk, callback);
  }
Resources:
https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_write_chunk_encoding_callback_1
https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_push_chunk_encoding